# Create X509Certificate from PEM file not working in Npgsql 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, x509certificate, npgsql

I'm trying to connect a cloud Postgresql service through my ASP.NET application using Npgsql 6.0.8. In the connection details it's mentioned that "SSL Mode" should be set to "require". Also, they gave me a PEM certificate file to use as an SSL certificate.
After adding the `ca.pem` file to my project, I got this error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
An exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The key contents do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not match the certificate.'
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.ExtractKeyFromPem[TAlg](ReadOnlySpan`1 keyPem, String[] labels, Func`1 factory, Func`2 import)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(ReadOnlySpan`1 certPem, ReadOnlySpan`1 keyPem)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(String certPemFilePath, String keyPemFilePath)
```

Based on this I called `CreateFromPem` and `CreateFromPemFile` manually and surprisingly I saw the first one works when I read the `ca.pem` file myself and pass the string pem file, in contrast in the second one I'm getting the same error.

```cs
var pem = File.ReadAllText(certificatePath); // Reading the PEM file
var cert2 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(pem); // Creating from PEM string works as expected
var cert3 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("ca.pem"); // Creating from PEM file doesn't work
```

[image]

Do you have any idea what I have done wrong, please?

Comment: Does the PEM file contain both the certificate and private keys?

Comment: The encryption mode of key may work in your OS.  What OS?  What is your target project?  Using Net 4.7.1 or later and Win 10 or newer should always work.

Comment: @Charlieface No, the provided PEM file just contains the certificate

Comment: @jdweng I'm compiling on macOS and the target SDK is .NET 6. However, my question is why it's working when I read the certificate from the file and provide it to the first method, but it fails when I use the second method with the file path. I'm sure the filepath is correct

Comment: A PEM only contains the key while the certificate contains more than the key.  The first you are reading the certificate while the second you are reading the pem.

Comment: These functions work completely differently: `CreateFromPemFile` docs say *"Creates a new X509 certificate from the file contents of an RFC 7468 PEM-encoded certificate and private key."* but `CreateFromPem` says *"Creates a new X509 certificate from the contents of an RFC 7468 PEM-encoded certificate."* So one expects just a certificate, the other also the private key. I suggest you just read the file and pass it to the otehr function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Charlieface, so need to another way as Npgsql is using the second one out of the box